# How to make a control of changes similiar to github

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, git, compare

I develop a new admin panel for teachers, each teacher has permissions to amend a list of pages. When anybody changes a page, new text is saved in DB and the panel notifies admins that A teacher edited page B.

The problem is that admins can see only the last state of the page and don't understand the adjustments which were made between states of pages.
Obviously, I can store all states of pages in my MySQL DB but:

1) How to make a control system as gitHub?
(where a teacher can compare the states of pages)
or maybe I can use gitHub, how?
2) How to make it more efficient?

Any ideas are highly appreciated!
Many thanks

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: I use Mysql DB. Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a php script I used for similar purpose. I used it to compare changes in a document ( not code ) made by other users. I think this is what you are looking for. What you need to do is, cache or save as new the state of current document each time user saves with a revision number. Also store previous version in a column. Then in a revision page, you can get both document, and compare changes.

https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff

So in your database where you have the documents,

```
ID       Title       Body            Revision      Previous
1     Test Title     Test body.      1             0 
2     Test Title     Testing body    2             1
3     Some Other doc bla bla         1             0
4     Testing Title  My 3rd Rev.     3             2
5     Some Doc       No bla bla      2             3
```

This way, you can go through each revision and compare title and body changes side-by-side with FineDiff.

Comment: Many thanks guyfawkes,
I have just checked your script. it is what I'm really looking for!
 It would be wonderful to not save the whole text, but add for instance information about how many characters hasn't been changed before an adjustment. 

Because I don't need information about the piece of text that hasn't been changed.